# Не работает конструктор базового контроллера

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно в базовом конструкторе подключать сервис, чтобы данный сервис работал во всех контроллерах, наследующих базовый, но данный конструктор не срабатывает.
Выдаёт ошибку:

`Target [App\Services\GeneralAppLayerInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Site\Controllers\HomeController].`

```
use App\Services\GeneralAppLayerInterface;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController {
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public $general;

    public function __construct(
        GeneralAppLayerInterface $general
    ) {
        $this->general = $general;
    }
}
```

**GeneralAppLayerInterface**

```
interface GeneralAppLayerInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns an array with resources.
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData(array $params = null);
}
```

**GeneralService**

```
class GeneralService implements GeneralAppLayerInterface {
    public $path;
    private $settings;
    private $menu;

    public function __construct() {
        
    }

    public function getData(array $params = null){
        $data = some data;
        return [
            'data' => $data
        ];
    }
```

**AppServiceProvider**

```
use App\Http\Site\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\GeneralAppLayerInterface;
use App\Services\Site\GeneralService;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use DB;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @GeneralService - frontend service
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        $this->app->when(Controller::class)
            ->needs(GeneralAppLayerInterface::class)
            ->give(function ($app) {
                return $app->make(GeneralService::class);
            });
    }
```

**HomeController**

```
use App\Http\Site\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $data = $this->general->getData();
        dump($data);
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Поищите ответ на вопрос [здесь](https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-solve-target-apprepositoriesnewsrepository-is-not-instantiable-while-building-apphttpcontrollersmembernewscontroller?page=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно работать

```
   /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->bind(GeneralAppLayerInterface::class, GeneralService::class);
    }
```